# Is there a simple way to move clone of Rc into closure?

Tags: rust

I need to move a clone of `Rc` value into several closures. Is there a better way to do it rather than cloning it before every closure?

```
let val = Rc::new(my_val);

let val_clone = val.clone();
closure_func1(move || { do_stuff1(val_clone) });

let val_clone = val.clone();
closure_func2(move || { do_stuff2(val_clone) });

let val_clone = val.clone();
closure_func3(move || { do_stuff3(val_clone) });
```

Comment: Is it always the same `closure_func` and `do_stuff`?

Comment: No, they are different every time. I've edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: You should read this issue https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2407 and there doesn't seem to be "a better way".

Comment: Thanks for the link! It actually answers the question. Is there a way to close a question without answer on SA?

Comment: You could have each closure only borrow `val`, and clone it themselves: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=43ea2977256f7a9035ce1f3a411e07a8)?

Comment: @eggyal This does not actually move the `val`. In my case that's not an option.

Comment: You're not moving `val` in the question either, you're only moving `val_clone`?

Comment: @eggyal It's likely the OP's `closure_func` functions require `'static` of the closure function, so capturing by reference doesn't work.

Comment: @MaximGritsenko, usually to do this you would write an answer to the question containing the information that helped you, and then accepted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a utility function to remove the repetition:

```
fn with_cloned<T>(rc: &Rc<T>, f: impl FnOnce(Rc<T>)) -> impl FnOnce() {
    let rc = Rc::clone(rc);
    move || f(rc)
}

let val = Rc::new(my_val);

closure_func1(with_cloned(&val, |val_clone| do_stuff1(val_clone)));
closure_func2(with_cloned(&val, |val_clone| do_stuff2(val_clone)));
closure_func3(with_cloned(&val, |val_clone| do_stuff3(val_clone)));
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this little macro in the comments under [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2407):

```rust
macro_rules! enclose {
    ( ($( $x:ident ),*) $y:expr ) => {
        {
            $(let $x = $x.clone();)*
            $y
        }
    };
}
```

which you can use like this:

```rust
    let val = Rc::new("Hello World".to_string());

    closure_func1(enclose! { (val) move || { do_stuff1(val) } });
    closure_func2(enclose! { (val) move || { do_stuff2(val) } });
    closure_func3(enclose! { (val) move || { do_stuff3(val) } });
```

[Playground Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=80f280cb049025b41b18fed0248b6270)

It is slightly more general than user4815162342's solution in that you can specify any number of values of any type as long as they can be cloned.

I also found the [closure](https://docs.rs/closure/0.3.0/closure/) crate which allows you to specify any combination of moves, clones and others. You would use that like this:

```rust
    let val = Rc::new("Hello World".to_string());

    closure_func1(closure!(clone val, || { do_stuff1(val) } ));
    closure_func2(closure!(clone val, || { do_stuff2(val) } ));
    closure_func3(closure!(clone val, || { do_stuff3(val) } ));
```